# Vaadin 18 | Need to pass a message from client to server using Lit-Template and HTML text

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14, lit

I am trying to call server side function from client using littemplate. I have one problem for which I need help.
I am adding a HTML fromatted text on server side which has a custom component 'hello-world2'.

I am passing one attribute (name="Vaadin") in this custom component. I expect that when user clicks on 'helloButton' then the value 'Vaadin' should be sent to server and invoke 'acceptMessage'.
But as of now I am getting error as displayed on attached screenshot.

I am doing this because in my current application I already have generated HTML Table. And for few columns I am trying to incorporate and use <vaadin-button> HTML tag. So when user clicks on this button I expect a message/value on server side for further handling.

Please guide my how to do this.

## Lit-Template

```js
// hello-world2.ts
import { customElement, html, LitElement, property } from "lit-element";

import "@vaadin/vaadin-button/vaadin-button";
import "@vaadin/vaadin-text-field/vaadin-text-field";
import "@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout";
import { showNotification } from "@vaadin/flow-frontend/a-notification";


@customElement('hello-world2')
export class HelloWorld extends LitElement {

    public $server1?: HelloWorldServerInterface;

    @property({ type: String })
    name = '';

    render() {
        return html`<vaadin-vertical-layout theme="padding spacing">
        <vaadin-button id="helloButton" @click="${this.sendMessage}">Message Button</vaadin-button>
    </vaadin-vertical-layout>`;
    }

    sendMessage() {
        showNotification("Hello : " + this.name); //Works well, displays the notification
        this.$server1!.acceptMessage(this.name); // Issue here.

    }


}
interface HelloWorldServerInterface {
    greet(): void;
    acceptMessage(arg0: String): void;
}
```

## Java

```java
package com.example.application.views.helloworld;

import com.example.application.views.main.MainView;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClientCallable;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Html;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.littemplate.LitTemplate;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.template.Id;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@CssImport("./views/helloworld/hello-world-view.css")
@Route(value = "hello", layout = MainView.class)

@PageTitle("Hello World")
//@Tag("hello-world2") -- Commented, if I uncomment this then I can see two buttons on browser.
@JsModule("./views/littemplate/hello-world2.ts")
public class HelloWorldView extends HorizontalLayout {

     public HelloWorldView() {   
        
         Html html = new Html("<hello-world2 name=\"Vaadin\"></hello-world2>");
         add(html);
        
     }
     
          @ClientCallable 
          public void acceptMessage(String message) {
          System.out.println("Message from client : " + message); 
          }
          
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want `HelloWorldView` in Java to represent the `<hello-world2>` custom element it should extend `Component` instead of `HorizontalLayout` and you should uncomment the `@Tag` annotation and remove the `new Html` and `add(html)` parts. When you have `@Tag("hello-world2")` it means that by adding `HelloWorldView` to the page it actually adds `<hello-world2></hello-world2>` so when you also manually add it in constructor you would end up with `<hello-world2><hello-world2></hello-world2></hello-world2>` (which is why you would see two times the content).

Comment: Now when you have the `@Tag` commented out here and you extend `HorizontalLayout` it means that `HelloWorldView` = `<vaadin-horizontal-layout>` component (instead of being a direct Java API for the `<hello-world2>` custom element) on the client side and that the `<vaadin-horizontal-layout>` instance will get the `$server.acceptMessage()` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `HelloWorldView` in Java to represent a Java API for the `<hello-world2>` client side custom element it should extend `Component` (or `LitTemplate` if you want to use `@Id` annotations) instead of `HorizontalLayout` and you should uncomment the `@Tag` annotation and remove the `new Html` and `add(html)` parts.

When you have `@Tag("hello-world2")` it means that by adding `HelloWorldView` to the page it actually adds `<hello-world2></hello-world2>` as that is then considered as the client side representation of this Java component. So when you also manually add the HTML for it in constructor you would end up with `<hello-world2><hello-world2></hello-world2></hello-world2>` (which is why you would see two times the content).

Now when you have the `@Tag` commented out here and you extend `HorizontalLayout` it means that `HelloWorldView` = `<vaadin-horizontal-layout>` component as it inherits the `@Tag("vaadin-horizontal-layout")` from `HorizontalLayout` (instead of being a direct Java API for your `<hello-world2>` custom element) on the client side. And then the `<vaadin-horizontal-layout>` instance would get the `$server.acceptMessage()` method so you can't call it from `this` in `<hello-world2>` as it would only be declare on its parent.

Here's a working example (I tested it works) for what I think you're trying to do (or something similar):

`hello-world2.ts`

```js
import { customElement, html, LitElement, property } from 'lit-element';

import '@vaadin/vaadin-button/vaadin-button';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout';
import { showNotification } from '@vaadin/flow-frontend/a-notification';

@customElement('hello-world2')
export class HelloWorld2View extends LitElement {
  $server?: HelloWorldServerInterface;

  @property({ type: String })
  name = '';

  render() {
    return html`
      <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="padding spacing">
        <vaadin-button id="helloButton" @click="${this.sendMessage}">Message Button</vaadin-button>
      </vaadin-vertical-layout>
    `;
  }

  sendMessage() {
    showNotification("Hello : " + this.name);
    this.$server!.acceptMessage(this.name);
  }
}

interface HelloWorldServerInterface {
  greet(): void;
  acceptMessage(arg0: String): void;
}
```

`HelloWorld2View.java`:

```java
package com.example.application.views.helloworld;

import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.example.application.views.MainLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClientCallable;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;

@Route(value = "hello", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Hello World")
@Tag("hello-world2")
@JsModule("./views/littemplate/hello-world2.ts")
public class HelloWorld2View extends Component {
    public HelloWorld2View() {
        setName("Vaadin");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        getElement().setProperty("name", name);
    }

    @ClientCallable
    public void acceptMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Message from client : " + message);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is the use case for the `name` property here though or why you'd want to set it in the constructor of the component, but here I also added a setter for it in the Java API. Alternatively you could set the default value for `name` also in the TS file instead of setting it in the Java constructor.

It seems like you may want this `<hello-world2>` to be a component that is intended to be added to a view (instead of representing a whole view by itself). In that case you should have a TS and Java file (like above) for this component specifically and then use it in some view and the `HelloWorld2View` above should probably be named just `HelloWorld2` or similar so it's not confused to be a view.

```java
public class SomeOtherView extends Div {
    public SomeOtherView() {
        HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
        HelloWorld2 helloComponent = new HelloWorld2();
        helloComponent.setName("Vaadin");
        hl.add(helloComponent);
        add(hl);
    }
}
```

or

```java
public class SomeOtherView extends HorizontalLayout {
    public SomeOtherView() {
        HelloWorld2 helloComponent = new HelloWorld2();
        helloComponent.setName("Vaadin");
        add(helloComponent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and detail explanation. I do understand what you are saying.
But I have a different problem, lets assume my application generates the HTML text "<hello-world2 name=\"Vaadin\"></hello-world2>". Now how will I invoke "acceptMessage" or any function of server side using this HTML text only.

Comment: I can also see Vaadin provides HTML tag to generate button '<vaadin-button>Button</vaadin-button>'. Now if I add this html tag on a component I can see a button on browser but I am not sure how will I invoke any function of the server side when this button gets clicked. If you have working sample then this would also solve my problem.

Comment: First of all you should try to avoid creating HTML from Java strings in a Vaadin application when implementing views and components as there are components and the Element API which you can use as a higher level abstraction. Though there are some use cases where you might need to create HTML from strings for example if the HTML is coming from a database or some external system.

Comment: If you do create a `new Html()` that includes your `hello-world2` component, there will not be a Java component instance associated for that client side component and if you need to interact with it in Java code you will need to use the lower level Element API. There are many ways to do things as you can choose to write the UI code (of a component or a view) as declaratively as a LitTemplate or imperatively with Java code.

Comment: If you create `<hello-world2>` as plain HTML (no Java instance) then the `acceptMessage()` client callable needs to be declared for example in your view class that will create and add the HTML (like in your original example). In this case the `$server.acceptMessage` will be available on the view element (the parent of `<hello-world2>`) so you should be able to access it from `<hello-world2>` with `this.parentElement.$server.acceptMessage(this.name)` but this doesn't feel like a good way to do things. You might instead trigger an HTML event from `<hello-world2>` and listen for it in your view.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another working example which might be closer to what you want.

`hello-world2.ts`:

```js
import { customElement, html, LitElement, property } from 'lit-element';

import '@vaadin/vaadin-button/vaadin-button';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout';
import { showNotification } from '@vaadin/flow-frontend/a-notification';

@customElement('hello-world2')
export class HelloWorld2 extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: String })
  name = '';

  render() {
    return html`
      <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="padding spacing">
        <vaadin-button id="helloButton" @click="${this.sendMessage}">Message Button</vaadin-button>
      </vaadin-vertical-layout>
    `;
  }

  sendMessage() {
    const $server = (this.parentElement as HtmlElementWithMyViewServerInterface).$server;
    showNotification("Hello : " + this.name);
    $server!.acceptMessage(this.name);
  }
}

interface MyViewServerInterface {
  acceptMessage(message: String): void;
}

interface HtmlElementWithMyViewServerInterface extends HTMLElement {
  $server?: MyViewServerInterface;
}
```

`MyView.java`:

```java
@Route(value = "myview", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("My View")
@JsModule("./views/littemplate/hello-world2.ts")
public class MyView extends HorizontalLayout {
  public MyView() {
    Html html = new Html("<hello-world2 name='Vaadin'></hello-world2>");
    add(html);
  }

  @ClientCallable
  public void acceptMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Message from client : " + message);
  }
}
```

Though ideally you'd also have a Java component class for `<hello-world2>` and use that in the view instead of the `Html` component. That could look like this:

`HelloWorld2.java`:

```java
@Tag("hello-world2")
@JsModule("./views/littemplate/hello-world2.ts")
public class HelloWorld2 extends Component {
    public HelloWorld2() {
        setName("");
    }

    public HelloWorld2(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        getElement().setProperty("name", name);
    }
}
```

`MyView.java`:

```java
@Route(value = "myview", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("My View")
public class MyView extends HorizontalLayout {
  public MyView() {
    add(new HelloWorld2("Vaadin"));
  }

  @ClientCallable
  public void acceptMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Message from client : " + message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin sets a variable called $server you can't change this name. That's the reason you have an error because $server1 does not exist.

You should rename $server1 to $server and it should work.

Comment: I already tried below options but nothing worked for me. Everytime I got the same response.  1) public $server?: HelloWorldServerInterface; .... this.$server!.acceptMessage(this.name);  2) public $server: any; .... this.$server.acceptMessage(this.name);  3) As shown in the code above.

Comment: You have commented out `@Tag("hello-world2")`. I am not sure why you would see two buttons if uncommented, but I believe you need that annotation for Vaadin to assign `this.$server` for you.

Comment: When I uncomment this @Tag("hello-world2") then I can see two tags in browser. And name field is blank for the outer tag. 
I want to add Html html = new Html("<hello-world2 name=\"Vaadin\"></hello-world2>"); in a component and also I expect $server at client side so that I can return back the name field to server.

Comment: See my comments in the question above. It's clear why there's a problem with either double content or `$server` not working due to not using the APIs as intended. If you use the `@Tag` and skip adding the `Html`  you can add the `name` attribute in the constructor (Java constructor using the Element API, or in the LitElement JS constructor). I can probably post an answer with corrected working example a bit later after one meeting.

Comment: Ok, I will wait for the example.

Comment: I added an answer a while ago and just now edited it to add some more info.